# Background color getting changed when resizing browser while using video_player in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-video-player

I have been using **video_player** library in flutter and creating a web application using flutter.I have been using it to implement with some functionality but whenever I an changing the width of the my browser, my background colour and everything is getting changed to white colour. For example this is my complete code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class VideoPlayerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoPlayerPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoPlayerPageState createState() => _VideoPlayerPageState();
}

class _VideoPlayerPageState extends State<VideoPlayerPage> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
 

  String dataSource = "Some data source";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(dataSource)
      ..addListener(() => setState(() {
            videoPosition = _controller.value.position;
          }))
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {
          videoLength = _controller.value.duration;
          _controller.play();
        });
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test Video player'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF010101), //black colour
      body: Column(
        children: [
          if (_controller.value.isInitialized) ...[
            AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
            ),
            VideoProgressIndicator(
              _controller,
              allowScrubbing: true,
              colors: VideoProgressColors(),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _controller.value.isPlaying
                      ? _controller.pause()
                      : _controller.play();
                });
              },
              color: Colors.blue,
              icon: Icon(
                _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
              ),
            ),
```

**Here is the screenshot after the code runs:**
[image]

**Here is the screenshot after I change the width of the browser**
[image]

**I don't want the video background to be changed and set it that way only. Also other widgets are also getting color changes**. This code has been tested in Google Chrome. Kindly help me in solving this.

Answer (score 1):

I think these are related:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/85963

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77832

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89521

Setting web renderer to html is not a permanent solution, but this is the only option available now.

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
```